# StackOverflow error when server returns HttpSession object within Spring ResponseEntity

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, recursion, jackson, stack-overflow

In my Spring MVC Rest controller method, I am trying to return an `HttpSession` object within another custom object called `Token`, all of which is within a Spring `ResponseEntity` object, back to the client.

But for some reason, I am getting a `Stackoverflow` error, due to some *infinitely  recursive* `Jackson` databind problem, whenever I include the `HttpSession` object as an attribute within my `Token` class.

**I do not get the `StackOverflow` error when the `HttpSession` object is *not* in my `Token` class.**

Here is my `Token` class:

```
public class Token implements Serializable {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; 
   private HttpSession session;
   private  String value;
   public Token () {}
   public Token (HttpSession session, String value) {
      this.session = session;
      this.value = value;
   }
   public String getValue() {
      return value;
   }
   public void setValue(String value) {
      this.value = value;
   }
   public HttpSession getSession() {
      return session;
   }
   public void setSession(HttpSession session) {
      this.session = session;
   }
}
```

Here is my controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getData", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<Token> getData(HttpServletRequest request) {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    Token t = new Token(session, "value");
    return new ResponseEntity<Token>(t, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Anyone know why this is the case?

Here is stack trace:

`Root cause of ServletException. org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext["securityContext"]->weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletSecurityContextImpl["servletContext"]............... com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155) at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:727) at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:719) at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155) at ........-`

Comment: HttpSession shouldn't be returned to a client. It's an in-memory server, private object. That likely contains lots of other objects. Hence the huge amount of serialization being attempted. What's the reason you think you want to send the HttpSession back to the caller?

Comment: @dbreaux I just thought that maybe the client can access some session info from the object if he needs it, but I'll approach it another way. Thanks